# How to set Outlook View for all folders?

Tags: xml, vba, outlook

I am trying to set the Outlook Layout for all folders to Compact.

I managed to recursively loop through all the folders, but I cannot find any information on what I need to change the layout.

I compared the XML of a Single Line layout vs the Compact layout.

In Office 2019, I found the XML node to make this happen (`<multiline></multiline>`) but in Office 365 the only difference I get when comparing both XML is the `<previewstyle/>`.

When I remove this node and load it (and apply) to the XML for the current view, it doesn't set the layout to Compact.

How can this be done programmatically?

Comment: What code exactly have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i removed the `<showpreviewheader>0</showpreviewheader>` row and it did the job (tested in office 365 application)!
Thank you all for the time taken.

[image]

```
<previewpane>
    <visible>1</visible>
    <markasread>0</markasread>
    <showpreviewheader>0</showpreviewheader>    <<< removed this row
</previewpane>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the required modifications in Outlook and then check out the XML markup of the current view in Outlook. So, you could be sure what changes are required. Here is what MSDN recommends when dealing with views in Outlook:

The [CurrentView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.currentview) property returns a [View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.view) object representing the current view. To properly reset the current view, you must do a `View.Reset` and then a `View.Apply`. The code sample below illustrates the order of the calls:

```
Sub ResetView()
 Dim v as Outlook.View
 ' Save a reference to the current view object
 Set v = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView
 ' Reset and then apply the current view 
 v.Reset 
 v.Apply 
End Sub
```

The `View` object allows you to create customizable views that allow you to better sort, group and ultimately view data of all different types. There are a variety of different view types that provide the flexibility needed to create and maintain your important data.

- The table view type (olTableView) allows you to view data in a simple field-based table.
- The Calendar view type (olCalendarView) allows you to view data in a calendar format.
- The card view type (olCardView) allows you to view data in a series of cards. Each card displays the information contained by the item and can be sorted.
- The icon view type (olIconView) allows you to view data as icons, similar to a Windows folder or explorer.
- The timeline view type (olTimelineView) allows you to view data as it is received in a customizable linear time line.

Views are defined and customized using the View object's [XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.view.xml) property. The `XML` property allows you to create and set a customized XML schema that defines the various features of a view.

The XML definition describes the view type by using a series of tags and keywords corresponding to various properties of the view itself. When the view is created, the XML definition is parsed to render the settings for the new view.

To determine how the XML should be structured when creating views, you can create a view by using the Outlook user interface and then you can retrieve the XML property for that view.

To programmatically add a custom field to a view, use the [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.viewfields.add) method of the [ViewFields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.viewfields) object. This is the recommended way to dynamically change the view over setting the `XML` property of the `View` object.